# Can Clojure generate function by macro?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to generator fn through macro.But I meet a strange issue.
Code is Here.

```
(defmacro test2 [lmk]
   (fn [lmk2] (println lmk lmk2)))
((test2 12) 13) ;;----->Error
(defmacro test3 []
   (fn [lmk] (println lmk)))
((test3) 12) ;;----->OK
(defmacro test4 []
   `(fn [lmk] (println lmk)))
((test4) 12) ;;----->Error
```

I know defn can work well.I just want to know why I can't use defmacro here.And why test3 works well,however test2 fails.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In test2, prior to compilation, the test2 macro will be invoked (lmk has not yet been compiled or evaluated) - because there is no syntax quote, this will actually evaluate the fn form and return a function object (with lmk closed over). So you then have the form (fn-object 13) passed to the *compiler*, which I think is going down an unexpected path (not sure exactly what that is). Interestingly this works:

```
(def f (test2 12))
(f 13)
```

In test4, the syntax quote will cause each lmk symbol to be resolved in the namespace so that's the source of that error. You really want autogensyming on those:

```
(defmacro test4 [] 
  `(fn [lmk#] (println lmk#)))
```