# constantly function not workint in syntax quote

Tags: clojure

If I do this:

```
(eval (let [f (fn [& _] 10)]
    `(~f nil)))
```

It returns 10 as expected.

Although if I do this:

```
(eval (let [f (constantly 10)]
    `(~f nil)))
```

It throws an exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for 
  class clojure.core$constantly$fn__... clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor
```

Since both are equivalent why is the code with constantly not working?

Comment: Plausibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/23542241.

Comment: If anything I would say the second behavior is the 'expected' one. The form you're trying to `eval` has an actual function object as its head, not a symbol or another expression: the compiler doesn't normally expect that. Note that the class of the anonymous function is going to be something like `user$eval141$f__x` while the second one is going to be an instance of `clojure.core$constantly$fn__x` which explains the *difference* but I'm not sure which behavior is to be expected

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistency in Clojure: functions in macros and IllegalArgumentException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427303/inconsistency-in-clojure-functions-in-macros-and-illegalargumentexception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has two answers, to really get it.

First, to clarify why your `eval` form is not giving you the expected result in the second case, note that `f` has been assigned to be equal to the *function* `(fn [& _] 10)`. This means when that form is evaluated, the function object is again evaluated--probably not what you had in mind.

tl;dr: `f` is evaluted when it is bound, and again (with ill-defined results) when the form you create is `eval`'d.

---

The reason why one (the anonymous function) works, while the other fails means we have to look at some of the internals of the evaluation process.

When Clojure evaluates an object expression (like the expression formed by a function object), it uses the following method, in `clojure.lang.Compiler$ObjExpr`

```
    public Object eval() {
    if(isDeftype())
        return null;
    try
        {
        return getCompiledClass().newInstance();
        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
        throw Util.sneakyThrow(e);
        }
}
```

Try this at the REPL:

Start with an anonymous function:

```
user=> (fn [& _] 10)
#<user$eval141$fn__142 user$eval141$fn__142@2b2a5dd1>

user=> (.getClass *1)
user$eval141$fn__142                                   

user=> (.newInstance *1)
#<user$eval141$fn__142 user$eval141$fn__142@ee7a10e> ; different instance

user=> (*1)
10
```

Note that `newInstance` on `Class` calls that class' nullary constructor -- one that takes no arguments.

Now try a function that closes over some values

```
user=> (let [x 10] #(+ x 1))
#<user$eval151$fn__152 user$eval151$fn__152@3a565388>

user=> (.getClass *1)
user$eval151$fn__152

user=> (.newInstance *1)
InstantiationException user$eval151$fn__152 [...]
```

Since the upvalues of a closure are set at construction, this kind of function class has no nullary constructor, and making a new one with no context fails.

Finally, look at the source of `constantly`

```
user=> (source constantly)
(defn constantly
  "Returns a function that takes any number of arguments and returns x."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [x] (fn [& args] x))
```

The function returned by `constantly` closes over `x` so the compiler won't be able to `eval` this kind of function.

tl;dr (again): Functions with no upvalues can be evaluated in this way and produce a new instance of the same function. Functions with upvalues can't be evaluated like this.

Comment: This is a well-written and thorough answer, but I've never heard of a function's closed-over variables referred to as "upvalues". Are there contexts/languages in which this usage is common? It looks like it might be a term popular in Lua.

Comment: Yes, I see it most in the context of Lua; that's where I learned it anyways.